# Adding border to just the news page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, navigation, border

I would like to add a dotted bottom border to my nav menu on just the news page.

Here is the site I'm working on so you can see what I mean: http://www.eclipse-experience.com/subdirectory

Any idea of what CSS I would use? Or is it conditional tags?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want to add a border-bottom to the "news" nav menu on every pages or do you want to add a border-bottom to the  "news" nav menu, when the current page is news??

Answer (score 0):

You could use inline styles in your header.php:

```
<?php 
if($post->ID == ID_OF_YOUR_NEWS_SITE) { ?>
    <styles>
        #nav {border-bottom:1px dotted #AAAAAA;}
    </styles>
<?php } ?>
```